# C GTK window inconsistently failing to redraw? (Thread1 updating object used by Thread2 unexpectedly??)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gtk, drawing

So I am working on a project in C on the Raspberry Pi Model 3B+ and I am using GTK to draw. I have GTK on its own thread and my program logic on its own thread.

Basically, my program takes pictures from 3 DSLRs using gphoto2 and saves them to jpgs, then GTK loads those JPGs, resizes them to 500x300 with a pixbuf and updates the picture in the GUI

The problem I am having, is that the GTK window will fail to redraw and it is very inconsistent when, sometimes it will happen after 11 pictures are taken, sometimes it will happen after even 2 or 3 pictures are taken, there is no consistent fault.

Any help would be appreciated, one thread just initializes gtk and then calls GTK main to do the GUI, and the other does my program logic, updates the jpg files and then updates the GTK objects for the gtk main to redraw. Maybe this has something to do with my thread updating the gtk objects at a bad time and the loop running gtk main crashes and halts??

My original GUI looks like this:
[image]

The black boxes arent the problem, those are just the default blank pixbufs before any pictures have been taken. The problem is that it will fail and the image will just turn to the background color (see on the grid "CAM2 Front") and then after this call the whole window glitches and does nothing. I can drag it around and it will draw stuff I drag it over but thats it.

[image]

I know it is the whole app that is failing to draw because I am getting results like this when I move the window around.

[image]

Any help is super appreciated. I have been playing around with this for a while now.

This is the code called by my program logic main thread loop to update the image to the new jpg taken:

```
void set_image_scaled(GtkWidget* img, const char* path) {
pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(path, &err);
g_assert_no_error(err);
pxbscaled = gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple(pixbuf, 500, 300, GDK_INTERP_BILINEAR);
gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(img), pxbscaled);
g_object_unref(pixbuf);
g_object_unref(pxbscaled);
```

}

This is the main logic thread that updates the GtkImage object (calls set_image_scaled()):

```
void* cam_main() {
while (running == 1) {
if (digitalRead(4) == 0)
    {
        printf("taking pics of %s item %i\n", (front == 1) ? "front" : "back", pic);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int fd, retval;
            CameraFile *file;
            CameraFilePath cfPath;
            strcpy(cfPath.folder, "/");
            strcpy(cfPath.name, "foo1.jpg");
            printf("Capturing cam%i...\n", i + 1);
            int res = gp_camera_capture(cams[i], GP_CAPTURE_IMAGE, &cfPath, context);
            //printf(gp_port_result_as_string(res));
            printf("capture result: %i\n", res);
            //Camera won't take pic if busy and will continue to program end
            char buf[256];
            snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s/cam-%i_%i_%s.jpg", workingDir, i + 1, pic, (front == 1) ? "a_front" : "b_back"); //a_ to make front come before back otherwise systems will order incorrectly
            fd = open(buf, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
            retval = gp_file_new_from_fd(&file, fd);
            retval = gp_camera_file_get(cams[i], cfPath.folder, cfPath.name, GP_FILE_TYPE_NORMAL, file, context);
            retval = gp_camera_file_delete(cams[i], cfPath.folder, cfPath.name, context);
            gp_file_free(file);
            //debug
            //if (front == 1 && i == 0)
                //set_image_scaled(front_cams[0], buf);
            if (front == 1)
                set_image_scaled(front_cams[i], buf);
            else
                set_image_scaled(back_cams[i], buf);
        }
        if (front == 1)
            front = 0;
        else
        {
            front = 1;
            pic += 1;
        }
        printf("pics taken...\n");
    }
}
```

}

My whole code for reference:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <gphoto2/gphoto2-camera.h>
#include <gphoto2/gphoto2-context.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <pthread.h>

    //program
    static int running = 1;
    //libgphoto2
    static CameraList* list;
    static Camera** cams;
    static GPContext* context;
    static const char *name, *value;
    static int ret, count;
    static int pic = 0;
    static int front = 1;
    static const char* workingDir;
    //GTK
    static GtkWidget *window, *vbox,*hboxDir, *hboxCamLabels, *hboxFrontPics, *hboxBackPics, *hboxStatus, *lblDir, *btnConfigDir, *lblCams, *lblFront, *lblBack, *lblCurrentStatus;
    static GtkWidget *front_cams[3];
    static GtkWidget *back_cams[3];
    static GdkPixbuf *pxbscaled = NULL;
    static GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = NULL;
    static GError* err = NULL;

static void btnConfigDir_ConfigureDirectory(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data) {
    GtkWidget *dialog;
GtkFileChooserAction action = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN;
gint res;

                dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File", window,
                                      action,
                                      "_Cancel",
                                      GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                      "_Open",
                                      GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                                      NULL);

res = gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
if (res == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
  {
    char *filename;
    GtkFileChooser *chooser = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (dialog);
    workingDir = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (chooser);
  }

  //gtk_label_set_text((GTK_LABEL)lblDir, workingDir);

gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
}

void* main_gtk() {
    //INIT GTK

    //SETUP WINDOW
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    //button1=gtk_button_new_with_label("Click me");
    //gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(button1), "click me 1");
    g_signal_connect(window,"delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    workingDir = "/media/pi/SD CARD";
    lblDir = gtk_label_new("Save to: dir\t");
    btnConfigDir = gtk_button_new_with_label("Configure Directory");
    g_signal_connect(btnConfigDir, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(btnConfigDir_ConfigureDirectory), NULL);
    lblCams = gtk_label_new("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCAM 1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCAM2\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCAM3");
    lblFront = gtk_label_new("Front");
    lblBack = gtk_label_new("Back ");
    lblCurrentStatus = gtk_label_new("Current Status: Idle");

    //SET WINDOW SIZE AND TITLE
    //gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 600, 400);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "CaptureGui");

    //RESIZE IMAGES
    //image
    front_cams[0] = gtk_image_new();
    front_cams[1] = gtk_image_new();
    front_cams[2] = gtk_image_new();
    back_cams[0] = gtk_image_new();
    back_cams[1] = gtk_image_new();
    back_cams[2] = gtk_image_new();

    GdkPixbuf* pxb;
    pxb = gdk_pixbuf_new(0, 0, 8, 500, 300);
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(front_cams[0]), pxb);
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(front_cams[1]), pxb);
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(front_cams[2]), pxb);
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(back_cams[0]), pxb);
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(back_cams[1]), pxb);
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(back_cams[2]), pxb);

    //g_print("1");

    //front_cams[0] = gtk_image_new_from_file("/media/pi/SD CARD/cam-1_0_a_front.jpg");
    //set_image_scaled(front_cams[0], "/media/pi/SD CARD/cam-1_1_a_front.jpg");
    //set_image_scaled(front_cams[1], "/media/pi/SD CARD/cam-1_1_a_front.jpg");
    //set_image_scaled(front_cams[2], "/media/pi/SD CARD/cam-1_1_b_back.jpg");

    //PACK
    hboxDir = gtk_box_new(0, 0);
    hboxCamLabels = gtk_box_new(0, 0);
    hboxFrontPics = gtk_box_new(0, 0);
    hboxBackPics = gtk_box_new(0, 0);
    hboxStatus = gtk_box_new(0, 0);
    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(0, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(hboxDir), btnConfigDir, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(hboxDir), lblDir, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hboxCamLabels), lblCams, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hboxFrontPics), lblFront, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hboxFrontPics), front_cams[0], 0, 0, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hboxFrontPics), front_cams[1], 0, 0, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hboxFrontPics), front_cams[2], 0, 0, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hboxBackPics), lblBack, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hboxBackPics), back_cams[0], 0, 0, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hboxBackPics), back_cams[1], 0, 0, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hboxBackPics), back_cams[2], 0, 0, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hboxStatus), lblCurrentStatus, 0, 0, 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hboxDir, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hboxCamLabels, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hboxFrontPics, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hboxBackPics, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hboxStatus, 0, 0, 0);


    //gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), front_cams[0], 0, 0, 0);
    //gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), front_cams[1], 0, 0, 0);
    //gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), front_cams[2], 0, 0, 0);
    //gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), back_cams[0], 0, 0, 0);
    //gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), back_cams[1], 0, 0, 0);
    //gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), back_cams[2], 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    //ADD ELEMENTS TO GUI
    //gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image1);
    //gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image2);
    //image2 = gtk_image_new_from_file("/media/pi/SD CARD/cam-1_0_b_back.jpg");
    //gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image2);

    //SHOW GUI
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}

void set_image_scaled(GtkWidget* img, const char* path) {
    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(path, &err);
    g_assert_no_error(err);
    pxbscaled = gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple(pixbuf, 500, 300, GDK_INTERP_BILINEAR);
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(img), pxbscaled);
    g_object_unref(pixbuf);
    g_object_unref(pxbscaled);
}

void* cam_main() {
    while (running == 1) {
    if (digitalRead(4) == 0)
        {
            printf("taking pics of %s item %i\n", (front == 1) ? "front" : "back", pic);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                int fd, retval;
                CameraFile *file;
                CameraFilePath cfPath;
                strcpy(cfPath.folder, "/");
                strcpy(cfPath.name, "foo1.jpg");
                printf("Capturing cam%i...\n", i + 1);
                int res = gp_camera_capture(cams[i], GP_CAPTURE_IMAGE, &cfPath, context);
                //printf(gp_port_result_as_string(res));
                printf("capture result: %i\n", res);
                //Camera won't take pic if busy and will continue to program end
                char buf[256];
                snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s/cam-%i_%i_%s.jpg", workingDir, i + 1, pic, (front == 1) ? "a_front" : "b_back"); //a_ to make front come before back otherwise systems will order incorrectly
                fd = open(buf, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
                retval = gp_file_new_from_fd(&file, fd);
                retval = gp_camera_file_get(cams[i], cfPath.folder, cfPath.name, GP_FILE_TYPE_NORMAL, file, context);
                retval = gp_camera_file_delete(cams[i], cfPath.folder, cfPath.name, context);
                gp_file_free(file);
                //debug
                //if (front == 1 && i == 0)
                    //set_image_scaled(front_cams[0], buf);
                if (front == 1)
                    set_image_scaled(front_cams[i], buf);
                else
                    set_image_scaled(back_cams[i], buf);
            }
            if (front == 1)
                front = 0;
            else
            {
                front = 1;
                pic += 1;
            }
            printf("pics taken...\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Kill any processes using cams
    system("pkill -f gphoto2");

    //main_gtk();
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    //Wiring pi init
    wiringPiSetupGpio();

    //Init
    context = gp_context_new();

    detect_cams();

    pthread_t logic_thread_handle, gui_thread_handle;
    pthread_create(&logic_thread_handle, NULL, cam_main, NULL);
    pthread_create(&gui_thread_handle, NULL, main_gtk, NULL);
    pthread_join(gui_thread_handle, 0);
    pthread_join(logic_thread_handle, 0);

    //Deinit
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        gp_camera_exit(cams[i], context);
        gp_camera_free(cams[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void detect_cams() {
    //Detecting all cameras and loading them into mem
        //Detecting all cameras
    ret = gp_list_new(&list);
    if (ret < GP_OK) return 1;
    gp_list_reset(list);
    count = gp_camera_autodetect(list, context);
    if (count < 1)
    {
        printf("No cameras detected.\n");
        return 1;
    }


    //Open all cameras
    printf("Number of cameras: %d\n", count);
    cams = calloc(sizeof (Camera*), count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        gp_list_get_name(list, i, &name);
        gp_list_get_value(list, i, &value);
        ret = open_cam(&cams[i], name, value, context);
        if (ret < GP_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "Camera %s on port %s failed to open\n", name, value);
    }
}

int open_cam(Camera ** camera, const char *model, const char *port, GPContext *context) {
    GPPortInfoList      *portinfolist = NULL;
    CameraAbilitiesList *abilities = NULL;
    int     ret, m, p;
    CameraAbilities a;
    GPPortInfo  pi;

    ret = gp_camera_new (camera);
    if (ret < GP_OK) return ret;

    if (!abilities) {
        /* Load all the camera drivers we have... */
        ret = gp_abilities_list_new (&abilities);
        if (ret < GP_OK) return ret;
        ret = gp_abilities_list_load (abilities, context);
        if (ret < GP_OK) return ret;
    }

    /* First lookup the model / driver */
        m = gp_abilities_list_lookup_model (abilities, model);
    if (m < GP_OK) return ret;
        ret = gp_abilities_list_get_abilities (abilities, m, &a);
    if (ret < GP_OK) return ret;
        ret = gp_camera_set_abilities (*camera, a);
    if (ret < GP_OK) return ret;

    if (!portinfolist) {
        /* Load all the port drivers we have... */
        ret = gp_port_info_list_new (&portinfolist);
        if (ret < GP_OK) return ret;
        ret = gp_port_info_list_load (portinfolist);
        if (ret < 0) return ret;
        ret = gp_port_info_list_count (portinfolist);
        if (ret < 0) return ret;
    }

    /* Then associate the camera with the specified port */
        p = gp_port_info_list_lookup_path (portinfolist, port);
        switch (p) {
        case GP_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PORT:
                fprintf (stderr, "The port you specified "
                        "('%s') can not be found. Please "
                        "specify one of the ports found by "
                        "'gphoto2 --list-ports' and make "
                        "sure the spelling is correct "
                        "(i.e. with prefix 'serial:' or 'usb:').",
                                port);
                break;
        default:
                break;
        }
        if (p < GP_OK) return p;

        ret = gp_port_info_list_get_info (portinfolist, p, &pi);
        if (ret < GP_OK) return ret;
        ret = gp_camera_set_port_info (*camera, pi);
        if (ret < GP_OK) return ret;
    return GP_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[You **cannot** use GTK from different threads](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html); only the thread that calls `gtk_init()` and `gtk_main()` can operate on GTK (and GDK) API.

The appropriate way to use threads within a GTK application is to use a worker thread for your long-running, blocking code, and whenever you need to update the GUI, use [`g_main_context_invoke()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-context-invoke) with a `NULL` main context.

Alternatively, you can use [`GTask`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GTask.html) to create your own asynchronous task running in a thread, and update the GUI once the task terminates.

In your example code, you should only ever call `set_image_scaled()` through `g_main_context_invoke()`, and you should not put the GUI inside its own thread.

Comment: The problem though is that I need to call GTK redraw functions. GUI has to be on its own thread because once i call gtk_main() the code will pause there until execution is done. I have to create another thread that then relys on my program logic to update the gui. If I don't have 2 threads its either the GUI that shows or the actual functionality of my program. Any suggestions on what I should do in this case?

Comment: I did explain what you need to do: either you call `g_main_context_invoke()` from the worker thread every time you need to update the UI, or you isolate the worker threads as a GTask.